# MQ Connection timeout c#

Tags: c#, timeout, ibm-mq, mq

I'm trying to connect to MQ Series 8 using c#.
I'm using the next code :

```
 try{
MQEnvironment.Hostname = "xxx";
MQEnvironment.Channel = "xxx";
MQEnvironment.Port = 111;
MQEnvironment.properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);

MQQueueManager mqmm = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);

}catch(Exception e){Console.WriteLine("Error : "+e);}
```

How can i set a timeOut connection in this case ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the socket time out via the `Connect_Timeout` parameter under the TCP stanza in mqclient.ini file. Since socket is a machine resource, connection timeout needs to be set in mqclient.ini file and the change will affect all MQ connections originating from that machine.

See here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016910_.htm

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the client will be a c# client no a machine, can i set   form my c# client?

Comment: Are you using re-distributable package and not installed MQ Client?

Comment: If yes, you can set the Connect_Timeout in app.config file as documented here http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016840_.htm